# grabbing a variable two parents up and a sibling over using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to grab a variable that is two divs up and a siblings over. However, the current code below seems to return no value.

There can be an infinite number of content_container divs. The jQuery below is what I am trying to use to find the value from the "value_to_grab" class within the same content_container div that the button_clicked div.

here is the HTML:

```
<div class="content_container">
       <div class="container_a">

              <input type="text" class="value_to_grab">

        </div>
        <div class="container_b">
               <div class="container_c">
                          <div class="button_clicked">
                              click
                          </div>
               </div>
        </div>
 </div>
<div class="content_container">   
    <div class="container_a">

              <input type="text" class="value_to_grab">

        </div>
        <div class="container_b">
               <div class="container_c">
                          <div class="button_clicked">
                              click
                          </div>
               </div>
        </div>
   </div> 
    <div class="content_container">
        <div class="container_a">

              <input type="text" class="value_to_grab">

        </div>
        <div class="container_b">
               <div class="container_c">
                          <div class="button_clicked">
                              click
                          </div>
               </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

here is the jquery:

```
    $(".button_clicked").live('click', function () {
        var value_to_grab = $(this).parent().parent().siblings(".value_to_grab").attr('value');

});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated.  Use `.on()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var value_to_grab = $(this).closest('.content_container').find('.value_to_grab').val();
```